Stopping Autofac-Registered Background Services via External Requests
I have multiple background services that are generally categorized by their operation types (e.g., daily, monthly). To avoid defining features like exception logging and task execution control (the PerformTaskCondition function) in each service, I created a base class.
My first question is whether the cancellation tokens of the classes derived from this base class, such as
BackgroundServiceA : BaseBackgroundService 
BackgroundServiceB : BaseBackgroundService

will be shared? If one of them shuts down, will all of them shut down?
    public abstract class BaseBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
     private IExceptionDal _exceptionDal;
     ... and a few data access layer classes

     public BaseBackgroundService(IExceptionDal exceptionDal, ...)
     {
      _exceptionDal = exceptionDal;
      ...
     }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                if (PerformTaskCondition(JobType))
                    var success = await ProcessAsync(stoppingToken);
            }
            catch(Exeption)
            {
                LogException(ex);
            }
            await Task.Delay(CalculateDelay(JobTypeEnum JobType), stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    protected abstract Task<bool> ProcessAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
    private void LogException(Exception ex){...}
    private static bool PerformTaskCondition(JobTypeEnum JobType){...}

}

My second question is that I want to stop these background services via external requests. I registered these services in Autofac. However, when I try to call and stop the service using the following method, I encounter an error Exception has occurred: CLR/Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException Exception thrown: 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' in Autofac.dll: 'An exception was thrown while activating BackgroundServiceA.'
public class BackgroundServiceManager : IBackgroundServiceService
  {
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _factory;
    public BackgroundServiceManager(IServiceScopeFactory factory)
    {
      _factory = factory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
    }
    
    public async Task StopService()
    {
      using var scope = _factory.CreateScope();

      var backGroundService = 
      scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<BackgroundServiceA>();
      var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
      cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

      await backGroundService.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
  }



CancellationToken in ExecuteAsync will be triggered once your service gets shut down by the host, like when the entire app gets shuts down (usually gracefully). See BackgroundService base class
Proper cancellation would be either via IHostApplicationLifetime(stops the entire app) or add CancellationTokenSource into the IoC container(one per service), resolve it in the service's constructor, and create a linked token source to monitor the cancellation signal in ExecutAsync. Here is a draft of the idea:

BackgroundServiceA(CancellationTokenSource cts)
...
ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    using CancellationTokenSource linked = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cts.Token, stoppingToken);
    ...
...
CancellationTokenSource serviceACts = new();
services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceA>(sp => new BackgroundServiceA(serviceACts));
...
services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceManager>(sp => new BackgroundServiceManager(serviceACts, serviceBCts))

